# Error caused page to close and reopen - PHP/HTML

Tags: php, mysql, performance, internet-explorer

I'm writing a query that checks a column to see if it has a value of 0 and then list all of the findings in a table.  The data consist of 5 columns and 140 rows of possible data.

Whenever I load this page it takes 8 - 10 seconds to load and then gives me an error saying that an error with the webpage cause IE to close and reopen the page.  Any idea what could be causing this error or the long load time?

```
<?php 
include 'login.php';

   $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What's in your login.php?

Comment: possibly coming from your server not your code?

Comment: Also do other browsers behave in the same way?

Comment: Fred - my login.php file contains host, user, password and database variables.

Comment: I've tried taking the variables out and using the user/pw instead and I received the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might not be establishing your connection correctly.

This line -

```
$con-mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
```

appears that you are trying to connect to the database, but is incorrectly written as a variable.

Also judging by your `mysqli_close($con)` statement, it's clear to me that you meant to assign `$con` to the connection.

Try,

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);
```

Comment: Your code here looks flawless then.  Do as @Fred said and share your login.php file. the culprit is probably in there.  You can (and should) of course, mask your user/pass that is in there.

Comment: The login.php page includes `<?php  $host = "host"; $user = "username"; $pw = "password"; $db = "database";  ?>`  That's all that is in the file.